# Update Syntax for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have a table with the following columns Job, Group, Desc, NGNT, 2010, 2011
I added the column Current Wages to the table and I need the data in this column to be equal to the 2011 column data, I know i have to use an UPDATE query but I cant figure out the syntax

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 2):

this should do it

```
update Table
set [Current Wages] = [2011]
```

You could of course have used a computed column instead or a view where you alias the 2011 column as Current Wages

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
UPDATE table
SET [Current Wages] = [2011]
```

Answer (score 1):

Update table set [current wages]= [2011]